# Validation with total 4 digit and only 2 digit after decimal

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate some data in java script where I can enter values >= 0.25 to 99.0 and Only 2 digit after decimal.

Comment: Did you attempt to write some code? Also any data example would be useful.

Comment: use toFixed() to get correct decimals

Comment: you can try the following regex: \d{1, 2}\.\d{2}.

Comment: @JunbangHuang  I need some extra validation also i.e. min value is 0.25 and it should not proceed further for .0 or 0. Here are the valid values --> 0.25, .25, 1, 1.22, 99.00, 99...

Comment: @YashwantSingh so the only 2 digit thing is an optional or a must? like can I do 1? or the formate have to be 1.00?

Comment: Yes, you can write 1 as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```js
frm.onsubmit = function () {
    var value = frm.num.value;
    if (+value >= 0.25 && +value <= 99 && /^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(value)) {
        msg.textContent = 'ok';
        return false; // remove this to allow submission to happen
    } else {
        msg.textContent = 'not valid';
        return false;
    }
};
```

```html
<form id="frm">
    <input name="num">&nbsp;<span id="msg"></span><br>
    <button>Validate and Submit</button>
</form>
```